# 'Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.Address' cannot be serialized

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wse3.0

I'm trying to write a WCF wrapper web service for a WSE3/ASMX web service. 
[The ugly reason why is that a 3rd party vendor won't support SSL and that is what's needed for BizTalk 2009 WCF adapter to work with WS-Security.  So if the vendor doesn't change - I need to call a local WCF web service...]

I followed this article to get the WSE3 proxy-builder built-in to VS2008: 
http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/jyoung/archive/2008/08/29/345.aspx
I make a web reference to the vendor's .asmx remote web service.

I build and publish my webservice locally, and just try to bring it up in the browser, and get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An
>   exception was thrown in a call to a
>   WSDL export extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>   contract:
>   http://tempuri.org/:IValuationService
>   ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException:
>   Type
>   'Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.Address'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking
>   it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  See
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported
>   types.

How can I make an object that I didn't write ('Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.Address') serializeable?  Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying?

Thanks,

Neal Walters

---

Additional Info - Monday Nov 16, 2009:

---

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IValuationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ExpressLync.ValuationServiceWse GetPropertyInfoSourceRecordPolicyNum(string PolicyNumber);
}
// end of interface 

// here is part of reference.cs...
public partial class ValuationServiceWse : Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol {
...
```

The only place I can find any reference what-so-ever to 'Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.Address'
is here, on the metadata when I do a "go to definition" of the Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml;

namespace Microsoft.Web.Services3
{
    public class WebServicesClientProtocol : SoapHttpClientProtocol
    {
        public WebServicesClientProtocol();

        public EndpointReference Destination { get; set; }
        public Pipeline Pipeline { get; set; }
        public SoapContext RequestSoapContext { get; }
        public bool RequireMtom { get; set; }
        public SoapContext ResponseSoapContext { get; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool UseDefaultCredentials { get; set; }

        public TSecurityToken GetClientCredential<TSecurityToken>() where TSecurityToken : Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityToken;
        protected override XmlReader GetReaderForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize);
        public TSecurityToken GetServiceCredential<TSecurityToken>() where TSecurityToken : Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityToken;
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri);
        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request);
        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result);
        protected override XmlWriter GetWriterForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize);
        public void SetClientCredential<TSecurityToken>(TSecurityToken clientToken) where TSecurityToken : Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityToken;
        public void SetPolicy(Policy policy);
        public void SetPolicy(string policyName);
        public void SetServiceCredential<TSecurityToken>(TSecurityToken serviceToken) where TSecurityToken : Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.SecurityToken;
    }
}
```

So in other words, how do I get rid of 'Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.Address'? 
It seems that EndpointReference is in the 'Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.Address' object.  So if I use the WSE3 generated code, it tries to serialize it.

So I think the solution will be to write yet another wrapper that is WSE3 free - and expose it via WCF.  But the trick is that the vendors web services has numerous large and complex objects - which now all inherit from Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol (since I'm using the WS3 code generator).  I really don't want to manually build all of them again.  In the example above, "ValuationService" is just one of such objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here was the problem.  I was getting a little cloudy and lost in the complexity of this application which exposes 4 services and dozens of methods, and the first time to ever use WSE3 from WCF.

The error was because the wrapper I wrote was trying to return the ValuationService itself. That was a dumb mistake.  The ValuationService did implement the Microsoft.Web.WebServices3.WebServicesClientProtocol  which included the Addressing class which was causing the problem.

The wrapper was supposed to use the ValuationService as a client, and return only the Valuation (or ValuationResult).  The valuationResult is of course just an object consisting of strings, decimals, booleans, etc... which can be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make something serializable "after the fact". The question is: what do you need that "Address" for?

Could you possibly change your WCF wrapper so that you'd be passing an address (if that's an URL as I suspect) as a string from your client to your WCF service, and then create an instance of "Address" inside your WCF service class?

Comment: How do I get rid of 'Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.Address'?  It seems to be "inserting itself. It's nothing I wanted to specifically include.

Comment: Solved - see my answer below.